# print all directories and subdirectories recursive in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

i am so new to shell script so i try to find out from google but could not find any solution or any similiar code for my needs.
i simply need to ls a folder that contains subfolders and many files in a certain format.
eg. i have a main folder folderA and 2 sub folder A1 and A2 within these folders there are 5 sub folders also

```
/folderA 
   /folderA1
      /folderA11
      /folderA12
   /folderA2
      /folderA21
      /folderA22
      /folderA23
```

finnaly i need to print these folders in this format :

```
1: folderA 
   11 : folderA1
           111 : folderA11
           112 : folderA12
   12 : folderA2
           121 : folderA21
           122 : folderA22
           123 : folderA23
```

i just need a simple loop code or similiar code to achive this in shell script..

thank you for any ideas...

Comment: does your system have the `tree` command?

Comment: And what have you tried it? How does it failed?

Comment: yup, try tree command

Comment: tree command do not exist :(

Comment: Hi Zsolt, i do not know hot to write recursive shell script so i could not try something

Comment: @Deniz What shell are you using? Do you have `/bin/bash`, `/bin/zsh`or `/bin/ksh`?

Comment: @konsolebox , we have /bin/ksh

Comment: What does `ksh --version` say?

Comment: well it gives me this error : "-version: 0403-010 A specified flag is not valid for this command." :( i dont know much about unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you're referring to the original Ksh:

```
#!/bin/ksh

function recurse {
    typeset PREFIX=$1 I=0
    shift
    for DIR; do
        if [[ -d $DIR ]]; then
            let ++I
            echo "${PREFIX}${I} : ${DIR##*/}"
            recurse "    ${PREFIX}${I}" "$DIR/"*
        fi
    done
}

recurse '' "$@"
```

Test:

```
$ ksh script.sh FolderA
1 : folderA
    11 : folderA1
        111 : folderA11
        112 : folderA12
    12 : folderA2
        121 : folderA21
        122 : folderA22
        123 : folderA23
```

Comment: may i ask you one thing more ? that can i add line numbers for each recurtion for like I=0 but only line numbers and i want keep them in a array like  (1: folderA1)  to an array[$i][$j].  Well my target is that a user will chose a number from the dir output and than i need to print proper directory within giving line number. And how i can remove the input when executing sh i mean the current directory should be the input

Comment: @Deniz Please consider posting another question about it with your current solution. Make sure you explain your intentions well along with example intended output. I might be able to but it would be difficult trying to answer it this way.

Comment: i will post a new one soon with more detailed meanwhile i ll try to understand your code :)  thank you ..

Comment: @Deniz I'll try to explain some. `shift` removes the first element in the arguments. e.g. with arguments like `1 2 3 4`, after `shift`, it just becomes, `2 3 4`. The `for` command when not given with `in` by default reads all values in the positional parameters so it's similar to `for X in "$@"`. I used `function` as well so variables declared with `typeset` becomes local to that function. This is helpful so that when the function is called again the variable from the previous function would not be altered by the new one.

Comment: `${DIR##*/}` is a special parameter expansion that erases everything that matches the pattern from the start of the string with greedy matching mode. A single `#` is not greedy.

Answer (score 0):

```
print() ( c=1; p=${2-1}; cd "$1"; echo "$p : $1";  
  for i in *; do test -d "$i" || continue;   
  print "$i" "  $p$((c++))"; done; 
)
```

Invoke this as `print .` to display the desired output for the current working directory, or `print /p/a/t/h` to display output for the directory at `/p/a/t/h`.